# PresentViewController with custom “scale-from-center” ModalTransitionStyle

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to implement custom view presenting transition style. Here is my code:

```
[myViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

I'd like to achieve “scale from center” effect while presenting views. I made a demo of desired effect with JQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/c7ztP/

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I would do is the following

From the initiating view controller i would do this

```
// OriginalViewController.h
newViewcontroller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.0f, 0.0f);
[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And on the receiving view controller I would do this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0f, 1,0f);
   }];
}
```

For this to work you'll need `QuartzCore.framework`. Also to make it sweeter I would add zero alpha to full alpha animated as it looks better.

Comment: When I try this the presenting view controller immediately gets hidden when [self presentViewController:newViewController animated:NO completion:nil]; is performed. The animation works but it's not on top of the presenting view but on top of a black background

Comment: i had trouble with this in ios7. I wrote this before i was using ios7. I found a way instead of presenting on self present on top window by finding the last object of view controllers on window.

Comment: On iOS 9, I had to adapt the answer a little bit (not sure, whether this holds for other versions, as well). First of all, the scale from `0, 0` would trigger the error `CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix`=> I used something above zero, e.g. `0.1, 0.1`. Secondly, the animation had to be defined in `viewWillAppear:`. Otherwise the presented view would not be rescaled, at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your own Controller with this animation effect.
Look at this controls: [KGModal](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kgmodal) and [UAModalPanel](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uamodalpanel).
Check theirs source code for animation example. It's not difficult to rewrite this code to support fullscreen view.