# Is there any way to assign no UIModalTransitionStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, uimodaltransitionstyle

I know there are four types of `UIModalTransitionStyle`s, but I would like not to use any of them.

However, this code doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    let modalView = ViewController()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Universal", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
    modalView.modalTransitionStyle = nil // Error: type 'UIModalTransitionStyle' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Whenever I don't specify the `modalTransitionStyle`, the compiler will get the `modalTransitionStyle` from the Storyboard document of `UIViewController`.

How can I set no `modalTransitionStyle`?

Comment: How are you presenting this `modalView`? can you show more code please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PresentViewController with custom “scale-from-center” ModalTransitionStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809727/presentviewcontroller-with-custom-scale-from-center-modaltransitionstyle)

Comment: @Wezly I added more code.

Comment: @LordZsolt Thanks for your input. It is not a duplicate since this answers are written in Objective-C.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that in your code the `modalView` is not even being used, the `vc` you are presenting is displayed from the storyboard.

Comment: Well translating the code from Obj-C to Swift shouldn't be a challenge...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not want a transition you should set the `animated` property to `false` when you present your new view controller.

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```